# How to convert WellKnownBinary and CoordinateSystemId to latitude and longitude

Tags: c#

I try to convert from WellKnownBinary and CoordinateSystemId to obtain the latitude and longitude.

I have a custom class named GeometriaDTO:

```
       GeometriaDTO geoDTO = oInstDTO.Geometria;
        DbGeography DBGeo = DbGeography.FromBinary(geoDTO.WellKnownBinary,(int) geoDTO.SRID);
```

But the last line throw the next error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
```

I'm going to do this:

```
double? latitude = DBGeo.Latitude;
double? longitude = DBGeo.Longitude;
```

How should convert to longitude and latitude?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve the question. I was using the Class DbGeography instead of DbGeometry.
The correct implementation is:

```
 GeometriaDTO geoDTO = oInstDTO.Geometria;
 DbGeometry DBGeo=DbGeometry.FromBinary(geoDTO.WellKnownBinary, (int)geoDTO.SRID);
 double? latitude = DBGeo.XCoordinate;
 double? longitude = DBGeo.YCoordinate;
```

I hope that it will be useful to someone.